# Regexp with accented characters on match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to check for forbidden words in a text area when a user tries to validate.
The forbidden words list is stored in the `jsBlackList` array, and this is part of my code so far :

```
var fieldValue = value;
var hasForbiddenWord = false;
for (i = 0; i < jsBlackList.length; i++) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\\b"+jsBlackList[i]+"\\b","gi");
    fieldValue = fieldValue.replace(regex, '***');
    hasForbiddenWord = hasForbiddenWord || fieldValue.match(regex);
}
value = fieldValue;
```

But the problem is, `jsBlackList` has some accented characters, while the user could write without accent (for example, jsBlackList can have "déjà", and the user has typed "deja", "déja" or "dejà").

How can I check for missing accents ?

NB about "Marked as duplicate" : the duplicate questions are about "regexp without accent to check text with accents", mine was "regexp with accent to check text with potential missing accents".

Comment: you can try this:  `d[ée]j[àa]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this i to change Your black list a bit:

Replace all characters with accent by same alternation.

For example: `"déjà"` to: `"d(é|e)j(à|a)"`

If Your blacklist is big, than probably You want to automate this replacements, but at the end it is convenient to have black list written like this.

Comment: character classes are more suited to this - d[ée]j[àa]

Comment: In the end, this is what I used. Had to redo the blacklist, but I suppose it's the best solution.

Comment: Character classes are good as well.
Readability preferences will probably decide.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a list of equivalences and in your regex OR all the equivalences:

```
dé|ejà|a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to:

- remove all accented chars in the blacklist,
- process text to replace accented chars with their non-accented equivalent

Then you can compare without bothering for accents.

Comment: That would be the easy way, but as you can see I have to replace the matched forbidden character to triple *. If I do as you explain, it would be harder to change only the matched word as the rest or the text needs to keep his accented characters.